# Scroll to given place on init based on the route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Got few components on my page one after another like:

```
<about></about>
<contact></contact>
```

etc.

I'm using the `ng2-page-scroll` to scroll to given section when the navigation link is hit, but I can't manage to scroll to given section on application init.

So when the user opens the page for the first time with `/contact` in the route, it would scroll down to contact on init, not stay at the top.

I use

```
if(this.router.url != '/') {
  let pageScrollInstance: PageScrollInstance = PageScrollInstance.simpleInstance(this.document, '#'+this.router.url.substring(1));
  this.pageScrollService.start(pageScrollInstance);
}
```

inside the constructor but it fires before the router sets the route on `router.url`

I've managed to use it normally with `window.location.href.split("/").pop()` to get the address before the router is set, but this happens before components are actually rendered and it scrolls to wrong position.

Is there a hook that triggers once and after the whole app with routing is set?

Comment: try within `ngOnInit()`. is there any problem with that?

Comment: @micronyks yes. `the router.url` is not as expected + the whole content is not loaded so it scroll to a wrong position

Answer (score 0):

With this, you can store `NavigationEnd url` to any variable(in service) and use it across your application.

This can be used(in **AppComponent**) to trigger changes between urls.

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
      //if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log('event', event)
      //}
})
```